# Should [verb] vs should be [verb + -ing]

Tags: phrase-choice

Do they mean the same? Or have slightly different meanings?'

Example sentence:

> Sorry, I'm rambling. We **should focus/be focusing** on the topic: your life.

Does this sentence change if the pick one option or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We should focus...
>
> We should be focusing...

"To be focusing" is to be already engaged in the act.

"To focus" is to engage in the act.

Comment: But If I say: "Sorry, we should be focusing on the subject matter." I think that means that we aren't focusing on the subject matter yet?

Comment: Yes, *Sorry, we should  be...* in your particular context is referring to something that is not happening but which ought to be happening.  In other contexts, it can be an emphatic assertion that what is being done should continue to be done, especially in response to someone who objects to it: *We shouldn't be spending so much time on my early years. --Yes, we should be. This probe must go back to your college years.*